# How to assign one variable to another in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

What I want to achieve is very simple, and I have tried few different things but none of them are working for me. I am using Django version 1.10 and python 3.4 (not sure if it matters)

This is what I want to do, `variable_a = variable_b` or `variable_b = variable_a`

**Failed Attempt #1:**

```
{% variable_a = variable_b %}
```

**Failed Attempt #2:**

```
{% with varibale_b as variable_a %}
{% endwith %}
```

**Failed Attempt #3:**

```
{{ variable_a|default:variable_b }}
```

**Failed Attempt #4:**

Filter:

```
@register.assignment_tag
def define(variable_a=None):
  return variable_a
```

template:

```
{% define variable_b as variable_a %}
```

Comment: you can't, have to sent it as a context

Comment: I wish I could do that, but the logic that I am using is quite complicated. Is there a way around to do this in the template?

Comment: I think you should rethink your logic. It not a harm to pre process a variable in the views.

Comment: If you still want to assign variables you have to you use the [Jinja2 template engine](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/). Jinja2 [has this feature](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#assignments).

Comment: there is always a way around, and I found it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution. This is the way to go,

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/545/

Edit: Write a small filter function that returns the value of the variable and capture that return value using the above tutorial. Simple!

Comment: Seems complex for such a simple task.Django wants all the processing to be done in the backend.That's why it doesn't provide lot of features in the template.